# Can't find the lowest number value in this dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to find the lowest number value in this dict which is **1.12498**

This is my code:

```
data = {'instrument': 'EUR_USD', 'granularity': 'H1', 'candles': [{'complete': True, 'volume': 7787, 'time': '2021-11-19T10:00:00.000000000Z', 'bid': {'o': '1.12987', 'h': '1.13046', 'l': '1.12830', 'c': '1.13000'}, 'mid': {'o': '1.12994', 'h': '1.13052', 'l': '1.12838', 'c': '1.13008'}, 'ask': {'o': '1.13001', 'h': '1.13059', 'l': '1.12846', 'c': '1.13015'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 5721, 'time': '2021-11-19T11:00:00.000000000Z', 'bid': {'o': '1.13002', 'h': '1.13023', 'l': '1.12839', 'c': '1.12892'}, 'mid': {'o': '1.13009', 'h': '1.13030', 'l': '1.12846', 'c': '1.12900'}, 'ask': {'o': '1.13016', 'h': '1.13037', 'l': '1.12853', 'c': '1.12907'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 7464, 'time': '2021-11-19T12:00:00.000000000Z', 'bid': {'o': '1.12894', 'h': '1.12968', 'l': '1.12516', 'c': '1.12565'}, 'mid': {'o': '1.12902', 'h': '1.12975', 'l': '1.12524', 'c': '1.12574'}, 'ask': {'o': '1.12909', 'h': '1.12982', 'l': '1.12533', 'c': '1.12583'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 9911, 'time': '2021-11-19T13:00:00.000000000Z', 'bid': {'o': '1.12565', 'h': '1.12935', 'l': '1.12488', 'c': '1.12873'}, 'mid': {'o': '1.12572', 'h': '1.12942', 'l': '1.12498', 'c': '1.12880'}, 'ask': {'o': '1.12580', 'h': '1.12950', 'l': '1.12508', 'c': '1.12887'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 11112, 'time': '2021-11-19T14:00:00.000000000Z', 'bid': {'o': '1.12874', 'h': '1.13206', 'l': '1.12870', 'c': '1.13066'}, 'mid': {'o': '1.12882', 'h': '1.13214', 'l': '1.12878', 'c': '1.13074'}, 'ask': {'o': '1.12889', 'h': '1.13223', 'l': '1.12885', 'c': '1.13081'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 8523, 'time': '2021-11-19T15:00:00.000000000Z', 'bid': {'o': '1.13065', 'h': '1.13208', 'l': '1.12996', 'c': '1.13172'}, 'mid': {'o': '1.13072', 'h': '1.13215', 'l': '1.13003', 'c': '1.13178'}, 'ask': {'o': '1.13079', 'h': '1.13223', 'l': '1.13009', 'c': '1.13184'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 5485, 'time': '2021-11-19T16:00:00.000000000Z', 'bid': {'o': '1.13170', 'h': '1.13215', 'l': '1.13122', 'c': '1.13178'}, 'mid': {'o': '1.13176', 'h': '1.13222', 'l': '1.13128', 'c': '1.13184'}, 'ask': {'o': '1.13183', 'h': '1.13229', 'l': '1.13135', 'c': '1.13190'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 6994, 'time': '2021-11-19T17:00:00.000000000Z', 'bid': {'o': '1.13176', 'h': '1.13191', 'l': '1.12916', 'c': '1.12977'}, 'mid': {'o': '1.13183', 'h': '1.13196', 'l': '1.12924', 'c': '1.12984'}, 'ask': {'o': '1.13190', 'h': '1.13203', 'l': '1.12930', 'c': '1.12990'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 4885, 'time': '2021-11-19T18:00:00.000000000Z', 'bid': {'o': '1.12977', 'h': '1.13022', 'l': '1.12861', 'c': '1.12864'}, 'mid': {'o': '1.12985', 'h': '1.13029', 'l': '1.12868', 'c': '1.12870'}, 'ask': {'o': '1.12993', 'h': '1.13036', 'l': '1.12874', 'c': '1.12877'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 3054, 'time': '2021-11-19T19:00:00.000000000Z', 'bid': {'o': '1.12863', 'h': '1.12914', 'l': '1.12848', 'c': '1.12888'}, 'mid': {'o': '1.12870', 'h': '1.12922', 'l': '1.12855', 'c': '1.12895'}, 'ask': {'o': '1.12876', 'h': '1.12929', 'l': '1.12862', 'c': '1.12902'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 2292, 'time': '2021-11-19T20:00:00.000000000Z', 'bid': {'o': '1.12885', 'h': '1.12911', 'l': '1.12854', 'c': '1.12875'}, 'mid': {'o': '1.12893', 'h': '1.12918', 'l': '1.12862', 'c': '1.12884'}, 'ask': {'o': '1.12901', 'h': '1.12926', 'l': '1.12870', 'c': '1.12892'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 1028, 'time': '2021-11-19T21:00:00.000000000Z', 'bid': {'o': '1.12874', 'h': '1.12892', 'l': '1.12795', 'c': '1.12808'}, 'mid': {'o': '1.12882', 'h': '1.12900', 'l': '1.12808', 'c': '1.12819'}, 'ask': {'o': '1.12890', 'h': '1.12910', 'l': '1.12820', 'c': '1.12830'}}]}

lowest_key = min(data, key=data.get)

lowest_value = data[lowest_key]
print(lowest_value)
```

But it give me this error: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'str'`

I think it not working because there list on the dict

Comment: isnt `1.12488` lower?

Comment: This is a nested structure. You could flatten everything and then within that find the smallest value where it appears, but you'll have problems comparing booleans to strings. It seems the numbers are mostly concentrated in the dicts for `bid`, `mid` and `ask` of each candle in the list. Is that what you want to extract?

Comment: @Reti43 I want to only extract the smallest number from all the number inside all the ```mid``` dict

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain

min(chain(*(candle['mid'].values() for candle in data['candles'])))
```

`values = (candle['mid'].values() for candle in data['candles'])` extracts the values of the `mid` dictionary of each candle. You can then use your favourite way to [flatten the list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists) and then just find the min value.

Comment: Excellent answer, I played around with this problem for the last 10 mins and was using function to sort and loop, good old itertools..... :D